# WPF ComboBox: Wrong Item is displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

This is the initial situation:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Margin="0,3"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"
           ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectSource}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public Collection<MyObjects> ObjectSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.objectSource;
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetProperty(ref this.objectSource, value);
    }
}
```

My Objects contains a name (string), valid from (dateTime) and a displayText (string only get) which combine the name and valid from for displaying.

In this easy situation I am able to open the combobox an see all entries, after selecting one it also display the right displaytext inside the combobox.
Now I open the the dropdown area again and select an other entry.
The result is that the slected item  switched (as you can see the highligthed item when open the dropdown entry again). But the displayed item inside the combobox does not changed, there is still the DisplayText of the first selection.

[image: Screenshot of the result situation]

Does anybody has an idea for me why the combobox does not update?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Thanks all for their help. Problem was a buggy overriding of Equals.

Comment: did you override Equals?

Comment: i have checked your problem but in my case everything just working fine..thr may be a problem that somehow your combobox is getting refreshed or it may be your collection..so just check it by using break points..

Comment: absolutely every thing is working fine on my system.

Comment: @blindmeis: yeah another devolper overide equals in our base class.
Does the combobox call this to compare the both elements?

Comment: You say you're selecting another entry but in the screenshot you haven't changed the selection yet. The selection of the ComboBox changes at the point that the popup list closes, not when the highlight in the popup changes.

Comment: @JohnBowen: The screenshot is from the moment i open the popup again after changing the entry.

Comment: @blindmeis: You are right, he calls Equals and there is a buggy overriding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just for completeness :)

you have to check your Equals() override and make sure thats not buggy.
i had the same problem with a listbox these days.

Comment: btw feel free to post both equals (good and bad) methods within my post.